# Which is the proper language for fenced code blocks when representing directory & file structure in Markdown syntax?

Tags: directory, r-markdown, markdown, syntax-highlighting, directory-structure

I want to represent my directory & file structure in Markdown syntax with fenced code blocks like this:

```
project
├── client
└── server
```

The thing is that my [Markdown linter](https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint/blob/v0.20.2/doc/Rules.md#md040) and other [Markdown Style Guides](https://cirosantilli.com/markdown-style-guide#option-code-fenced) recommend to `Always specify the language of the code` when using Fenced Code Blocks like this:

````
```language
a = 1
````

I was wondering if I should leave it without specifying a language, add a random one, or if there is a specific one for this situation that would highlight the structure.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's `text` for non-highlighted fenced blocks compliant with MD040. I'm not sure how much official in Markdown world that is but it is [listed](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml#L5433) in Github's linguist `languages.yml` as supported highlighted (in fact non-highlighted) language.

Comment: Thank you @blami for the answer and for the list you provided. I did not know about that option. I will use it for this purpose unless someone suggests a more appropriate one.